# matlab function sortrows in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to sort a pandas dataframe, as follows:

1. order by first column
2. if  two rows are equal in the first column then, order by second column,  if  two rows are equal in the second column then, order by third column, and so on.

I would like to obtain the same behaviour of this function in matlab (https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.sortrows.html#bt8bz9j-2)

is there a function in pandas for this?

I hope I have been clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In panda we have `pd.DataFrame.sort_values()`

```
out = df.sort_values(df.columns.tolist())
```